# Issues when implementing compareTo()

Tags: java, linked-list, bubble-sort, compareto

I'm trying to write a `compareTo()` method to use for bubble sorting. So far I have:

```
/**
 * Compares a ComparableItem to another ComparableItem
 * 
 * @param item a second ComparableItem
 */
public int compareTo(Trees name) {
    // convert names to lowercase
  String name1 = this.get().toLowerCase();
  String name2 =get().toLowerCase();
    // compare the two names 
        int result = name1.compareTo(name2);
    return result;
}
```

My problem is 1. how to use the get method as it is in another class. Currently I am getting these errors

> error: cannot find symbol
>         String name1 = this.get().toLowerCase();
>     symbol: method get()**
>
> error: method get in class LinkedList cannot be applied to given types;
>         String name2 = LinkedList.get().toLowerCase();
>
> required: Integer
>     found: no arguments
>     reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
>     where T is a type-variable:
>       T extends Object declared in class LinkedList

How can I fix this?

Comment: Please post all the source code of your class

Comment: Make `Trees` to implement `Comparable<Trees>` and put your `compareTo()` there. And consider using [`String#compareToIgnoreCase()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareToIgnoreCase-java.lang.String-) instead of converting to lowercase--it is faster and more reliable.

Answer (score 1):

`compareTo(Trees other)` (which belongs to the `Comparable<Trees>` interface) should be implemented in the `Trees` class, since it compares the instance of `this` class to the passed instance.

If you can't implement `compareTo` in `Trees`, you can implement `compare(Trees1 t1, Trees2 t2)` (of the `Comparator<Trees>` interface) instead.

```
public int compare(Trees t1, Trees t2) {
    // convert names to lowercase
    String name1 = t1.get().toLowerCase();
    String name2 = t2.get().toLowerCase();
    // compare the two names 
    return name1.compareTo(name2);
}
```

Comment: why not `.compareToIgnoreCase()`?